# Configuration of oracle 11g remote database with PL/SQL Developer 14

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, oracleclient

I need some assistance in configuring my oracle 11g database with the PL/SQL developer 14. I have installed and configured 11g client for my windows PC but the database is not show in the DBs list on PL/SQL 14 as:

[image]

But I got connected when I use PL/SQL Developer 7 as:

[image]

Actually, I want to use some advance features and plugins of PL/SQL Developer 14 which are not available in 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Actually, the issue was that the PL/SQL was 64 bit and the client was 32 bit that's why I had to download and install a 64 bit client which I installed and set the path to it's oci.dll file and that's solved my problem. One more thing I need to mention is that I have also created an environment variable for TNS_ADMIN and set the path to the folder which contains tnsnames.ora file.

Other answers are also appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't use PL/SQL Developer.

However, *any* tool I know looks for available databases in TNSNAMES.ORA file. It looks as if version 7 "knows" its location, while version 14 doesn't.

If it (PL/SQL Developer) behaves like other Oracle-related software, then I'd suggest you to do this:

- create a directory (folder), e.g. c:\oralib
- put TNSNAMES.ORA file in there
- create environment variable named TNS_ADMIN (uppercase!)

  - what does it do? It tells Oracle software where to search for TNSNAMES.ORA. Probably every Oracle software uses its own "copy" of TNSNAMES.ORA so - every time you have to work with a new database, you have to add its alias into ALL of those files (which is tedious). But, if you keep a single copy in a directory and let TNS_ADMIN point to it, you have only one TNSNAMES.ORA to maintain
- set its value to path that leads to that directory: c:\oralib
- restart PL/SQL Developer
- hopefully, you'll see your databases

Comment: The environment variable, in my experience, is `TNS_ADMIN` (with underscore).

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you, @nop77svk, fixed.